# Large select list taking long time to render in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, erb

In my rails application, i have the following code

```
<select id="gmm_list" name="multiselect" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple">
            <optgroup label="Exact">
            <% @exact_matches.each do |item|  %>
              <option class = 'matched exact' value='<%= item %>'> <%= item %> </option>
            <% end %>
            </optgroup>

            <optgroup label="Partial">
            <% @partial_matches.keys.each do |key|  %>
              <option class='matched partial' value='<%= @partial_matches[key]  %>'> <%= key %> </option>
            <% end %>   
           </optgroup>  

            <optgroup label="None">
            <% @no_matches.each do |item|  %>
              <option class='none' value='<%= item %>'> <%= item %> </option>
            <% end %>
            </optgroup>                     
</select>
```

Problem is that this select list contains 11,000 items so its taking a long time to render. How can i fix this ?

Thank You

Comment: Just wondering: is the user supposed to scroll over all those 11.000 items?

Comment: Yes, its a scrollable list